# AWS CLI moving file with wildcard (asterisk) in path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I am attempting to move a file, from on s3 location to another, using an activity in a AWS data pipeline.

The command I am using is:

```
(aws s3 mv s3://foobar/Tagger/out//*/lastImage.txt s3://foobar/Tagger/testInput/lastImage.txt)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
A client error (404) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "Tagger/out//*/lastImage.txt" does not exist
```

But, if I replace the "*" with the specific directory name, it will work.  The problem is I won't always know the name of the directory, so I was hoping I could use the "*" as a wild card.

Comment: AWS SDK does not support wildcards. Instead, you can search based on prefix (stuff before the wildcard). Then, you could grep the results for those ending in `/lastImage.txt`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wildcards in the AWS S3 CLI only work when using the `--recursive` flag.

So this should work for you:

```
aws s3 mv s3://foobar/Tagger/out/ s3://foobar/Tagger/testInput/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*/lastImage.txt"
```

Unfortunately, this will recreate the entire directory structure in your target location, and I'm not immediately sure that can be solved by just using the AWS CLI.